# Added folder to class library project, cant access the namespace when referencing DLL

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dll

I created a new folder in my project:

[image: desc]

Giving me a new namespace, like:

[image]

However, when I build this project, and reference the DLL from another project, I cannot find this namespace.

IE

```
using ClassLibrary1.MyFolder;
```

Once I type ClassLibrary1.  intellisense doesnt pick anything up, and the MyFolder part is red.

I have never had this problem before. I have rebuilt, cleaned solution, copy and pasted the refreshed DLL manually, checked to make sure its the latest DLL... I cant figure this out... im about to effing rage. Its been a long week. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you have any addin installed?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Framework versions of the dll and the project that you are referencing it from.  For example if you have a .net 3.0 project and you try to reference a library built with .Net 4, you will see this behavior.   You will also see this behavior if the library requires .net 4 full profile but your project is currently using .net 4.0 Client profile.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, even if you clean the class library, rebuild it, and put the .dll in the same folder that had the old version, the project that needs this .dll cannot recognize the changes of the newest version.

To fix this, you can delete the reference in your project and remake the reference, setting to the newest version. Your project will find the folders and everything else that wasn't there before this process.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your class is `public`, the default is `internal`.  `internal` members can only be accessed by code in the same assembly -- not from another assembly which is what you are trying to do here.

Comment: The question shows `public class Class1`, so this doesn't appear to apply here.